# (VBA) Different Result from Debugging Mode and Normal Run Mode

Tags: vba, debugging, execute

Now I am trying a **VBA** practice, but I discovered that there are **different results between debugging mode and normal run mode(F5)**.

I want to **make the colors that fill the cells shift to the right**, so that it works well when I run it through debugging mode, but normal run mode doesn't deliver the same.

I can't find why the same code make different results. Thank you for your help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Wave()

Dim StartRow As Integer, StartColumn As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim FirstColumn As Range, LastColumn As Range

StartRow = 1
StartColumn = 1
Width = 112
Height = 50
    
Range(Cells(StartRow, StartColumn), Cells(Height, Width)).Select
Selection.RowHeight = 10
Selection.ColumnWidth = 1

For i = 1 To Height
    For j = 1 To Width
        Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = (i + j) Mod 56 + 1 '
    Next j
Next i

For k = 1 To Width
    Columns(Width).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns(1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I tried also to avoid `select` and `activecell`, but I failed to realize the same effect with cut & paste by that way, so I should use `select` unwillingly. But I am going to try again with reference to the link that you give me. Thank you!

Comment: Use objects, you defined two range variables but never used them.
To avoid select, try something like this:
Instead of: 
        `Columns(Width).Select`
        `Selection.Cut`
        `Columns(1).Select`
        `Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight`
Use:
`With Wsh` use worksheet object
        `.Columns(Width).Cut`
        `.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight`
`End with`